# array math exponential

Tags: php, math, exponential

Hi I need to make an dynamic array  like this:

I have a max number of 25000 and 62 as exponential(?) number.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0  
    [1] => 3844     // 62 * 62
    [2] => 238328   // 62 * 62 * 62 <---
    [3] => 14776336 // 62 * 62 * 62 * 62
)
```

This is just an example of what I need: calculate the array values and find where fit the max number.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$max =  floor(log(25000,62));
$array = array_map(function($value){return pow(62,$value);},range(0,$max);
```

Or, in a total function:

```
function getpowers($base, $maxvalue){
    $max = floor(log($maxvalue,$base));
    return array_map(function($value) use ( $base ) {return pow($base,$value);},range(0,$max));
}
var_dump(getpowers(62,25000));
```

Comment: Hi, have some issues with php 5.2 can you help me?

Comment: These are basic maths functions in PHP which arent very version-dependant. What are your problems with this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
$max=25000;
$exp=62;
$result=0;
$i=1;
while ($result<$max)
  {
  $result=pow($exp,$i);
  $i++;
  }
echo $i;
echo '<br>';
echo $result;
```